# Imagesloaded not working with Infinite Ajax Scroll and Masonry

Tags: javascript, masonry, imagesloaded

I have a website the uses bootstrap and the news that I have created with masonry, I used the Infinite Ajax Scroll, that call other news in a different div instead the pre-default. Very often, however, if one scrolls the page quickly, or if you have a slow connection, the elements overlap and do not return to their place, and I think this is due to the fact that it can't load images.
I tried to integrate Imagesloaded but it seems not work properly... and I don't know what to do...
Here is the source as I have proceeded,
HTML:

```
<div class="row masonry_base altre">
  {$news}
</div>

<div class="row masonry altre">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12 post-grid">
    {$news_scroll}
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
(function($) {
"use strict";

  var $container = $('.masonry_base');
  $($container).imagesLoaded( function(){
    $($container).masonry({
      itemSelector: '.post-grid',
      columnWidth: '.post-grid'
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var container = document.querySelector('.masonry');
  var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
    itemSelector: '.post-grid',
        gutterWidth: 20
  });
msnry.reloadItems()
    var $container = $('.masonry');
    $($container).imagesLoaded( function(){
        $($container).masonry({
            itemSelector: '.post-grid',
            columnWidth: '.grid',
            gutterWidth: 20
        });
    });


  var ias = $.ias({
    container: ".masonry",
    item: ".post-grid",
    pagination: "#pagination",
    next: ".next a",
    delay: 1200
  });

  ias.on('render', function(items) {
    $(items).css({ opacity: 0 });
  });

  ias.on('rendered', function(items) {
    msnry.appended(items);
  });

  ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension());
  ias.extension(new IASNoneLeftExtension({
        html: '<div class="btn btn-info btn-block btn-icon-left ias-noneleft" style="text-align:center"><p><em>No news</em></p></div>'
    }));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code :

```
$($container).imagesLoaded( function(){
    $($container).masonry({
        itemSelector: '.post-grid',
        columnWidth: '.grid',
        gutterWidth: 20
    });
});
```

Only applies `imagesLoaded` to whatever `$container` happens to be at its execution. It doesn't apply to dynamically added content. You should call this function again to the dynamic content added. Perhaps in your `rendered` callback.

Also, you should just call `msnry.layout()` to adjust content after the images had been loaded (It's not necessary to call `$.masonry` again)

Hope it helps

Comment: I've modified the JS in this way, it is correct? `<script>
(function($) {
"use strict";

  var $container = $('.masonry_base');
  $($container).imagesLoaded( function(){
    $($container).masonry({
      itemSelector: '.post-grid',
      columnWidth: '.post-grid'
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var container = document.querySelector('.masonry');
  var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
    itemSelector: '.post-grid',
  });`

Comment: The problem should remain with that. Try changing the Infinite Ajax Scroll callback to this `ias.on('rendered', function(items) {
    msnry.appended(items);
    msnry.layout();
});`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, unfortunately if I insert "msnry.layout();" it causes me this huge empty space as you can see from http://i.imgur.com/HBULlAM.png

Comment: From your code, it's hard to tell. If you have a live preview or a JSFiddle may be I can check on it.

Comment: Resolved, was an error of tpl... Thanks for the help!